# get index of character in python list

Tags: python, indexing, character

What would be the best way to find the index of a specified character in a list containing multiple characters?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
>>> ['a', 'b'].index('b')
1
```

If the list is already sorted, you can of course do better than linear search.

Comment: what will it return if char or element is not present in the list?

Comment: it gives error in this case. Is there any function in python to find whether a char is present in a string or not ?

Answer (score 5):

Probably the `index` method?

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
print a.index("c")
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others, you can use `index`. Other than that you can use `enumerate` to get both the `index` as well as the `character`

```
for position,char in enumerate(['a','b','c','d']):
    if char=='b':
        print position
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def lookallindicesof(char, list):
    indexlist = []
    for item in enumerate(list):
        if char in item:
            indexlist.append(item[0])
    return indexlist

indexlist = lookllindicesof('o',mylist1)
print(indexlist)
```

Comment: This is a pretty old forum. I think the user who made this already knows how to do this, and also instead of using linear search, please use index searching.