# Index of entry in python list of which a chosen word is a part

Tags: python

I have a list in python with a few string entries. I want to compare this list with a word (say `thing`), and find the index of the entry in the list of which the chosen word is a part.

For example, let’s consider the following list:

```
lst = ['one_word', 'something', 'another_word']
word = 'thing'
```

Here `thing` is a part of the entry `something` in list `lst`. So, the index that I want is 1.

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847472/get-index-of-character-in-python-list). But, it requires the word to exactly match the entry in the list. My case is different. The entry in the list `lst` can have suffix or prefix (or both), after or before the word under consideration.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to pair elements with their indexes and use a common substring-check with `in`:

```
lst = ['one_word', 'something', 'another_word']
word = 'thing'

# 1: get all indexes
[i for i, s in enumerate(lst) if word in s]  # [1]

# 2: get only the first index (or None)
next((i for i, s in enumerate(lst) if word in s), None)  # 1
```

The first option uses a conditional [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build a `list` of all "word-containing indexes". 
The second option uses [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with an appropriate [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and default value.

If you want to check only for true pre-/suffixes instead of substrings, you can substitute `word in s` with [`s.startswith(word)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) or [`s.endswith(word)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).

Comment: schwobaseggl: Thank you so much for the wonderful answer. It is extremely helpful. I tested it; it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

you could simply loop over the list and check the word you search for against all the words in the list:

```
lst = ['one_word', 'something', 'another_word']
word = 'thing'


def word_in_list(lst, word):
    for i, w in enumerate(lst):
        if word in w:
            return i
    # python3:
    # raise ValueError(f'word "{word}" not in list')
    # python2:
    raise ValueError('word "{}" not in list'.format(word))

print(word_in_list(lst, word))
```

Comment: hiro protagonist: Thanks for your help. I am using Python 2.7. The ValueError statement gives an error for me.

Comment: @LingGuo ok, added the python 2 version.

Answer (score -1):

Though elegant approaches & answers already in place but just like to add Without enumerate():

```
>>> lst = ['one_word', 'something', 'another_word']
>>> word = "thing"

>>> listIndex = [lst.index(i) for i in lst if word in i]
>>> listIndex 
[1]
```

Or Simply

```
>>> [lst.index(i) for i in lst if word in i]
[1]
```

Note: This is likely to run in O(n^2), whereas using enumerate will be O(n)

Comment: I just update the answer to match the requirement and to get downvote removed :)